# Downloading multiple files into a Zip file Javascript using data URI

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am using EXT JS 4.2 which has a panel which contains a export to CSV button.

On clicking on it multiple (total six) files are downloaded. I want these files to be downloaded in a single ZIP file.

Comment: Have you tried to create a folder using JSZip?

Comment: I created a JSFiddle that works. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a perfect plugin to create zip files inside browser.

> JSZip: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Install the plugin by adding js files manually:

> download JSZip and include the file dist/jszip.js or
>   dist/jszip.min.js

JSFiddle - JSZip 3.0:

> https://jsfiddle.net/andrebonna/u8zsbzau/

```
var zip = new JSZip();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var CSV = 'CSV_content';
    // Fill CSV variable
    zip.file("file" + i + ".csv", CSV);
}

zip.generateAsync({
    type: "base64"
}).then(function(content) {
    window.location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
});
```